# Number of elements exceeds the maximum allowed in SQL pivot statement

Tags: sql, pivot, transpose

I'm having an issue when attempting to convert date values into 'Mmm YY' format then listing them as columns in my query results.  I found an example of the pivot command and because I don't understand it, I've done something wrong as I get the error message: "The number of elements in the select list exceeds the maximum allowed number of 4096 elements." but I know that there are fewer then 4096 months in the data I'm looking at (5 years rather than 341) so I know that the error is my code and suspect it's something to do with my grouping. Please help!

I'm running this in MSSMS 14.0.17289.0 and have tried running the code in the nested select statements on it's own.  It works when returning the date results as a column so I think that bit is right, but don't understand enough to determine the problem with the rest.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME('PDate') 
                    FROM [Live Company$G_L Entry] AS GLE
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = N'SELECT ' + @cols + N' from 
             (
                GLE.[G_L Account No_]
        ,CASE WHEN GLE.[Global Dimension 1 Code] IS NOT NULL THEN GLE.[Global Dimension 1 Code] ELSE 00 END AS "Branch"
        ,CAST(SUM(GLE.[Amount]) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS ''Amount''
        ,FORMAT(GLE.[Posting Date],''MMM yy'') as ''PDate''
                FROM [Live Company$G_L Entry] AS GLE
                GROUP BY GLE.[G_L Account No_],GLE.[Global Dimension 1 Code],GLE.[Pdate]
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for PDate in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

I expected the output to list G_L Account, Branch, Amount, Jan 17, Feb 17, Mar 17, Apr 17... etc as column headers with contents within.  At the moment the dates exist in a column under the header 'Posting Date'.

Answer (score 0):

I see several errors.

First you're not collecting the column names in the `MMM yyy` format. Actually as you've written it you're concatenating a series of the string literal `PName`.

```
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(FORMAT(GLE.[Posting Date],'MMM yy')) 
                FROM [Live Company$G_L Entry] AS GLE
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'');
```

To debug this in the future you'd want to use either `print @cols` or `select @cols` to see if it looks right.

The main query itself had other problems itself.

```
set @query = N'SELECT [G_L Account No_], Branch' -- presumably you want to see these too
    + @cols + N' from
    (select -- <-- missing from your query
     GLE.[G_L Account No_]
    ,COALESCE(GLE.[Global Dimension 1 Code], 00) AS "Branch"
    ,CAST(SUM(GLE.[Amount]) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS Amount
    ,FORMAT(GLE.[Posting Date],'MMM yy') as PDate
            FROM [Live Company$G_L Entry] AS GLE
            GROUP BY GLE.[G_L Account No_],GLE.[Global Dimension 1 Code],
            FORMAT(GLE.[Posting Date],'MMM yy') -- <-- correct grouping expression
        ) x
```

Again, dumping the output of the `@query` variable will let you see the query that's causing the error. Next time you post a question it would be incredibly helpful to see that.